# Is there an algorithm to figure out whether a certain polynomial over $ℚ$ is irreducible or not?

Tags: polynomials, algorithms, irreducible-polynomials

Just wondering

Does there exist an algorithm that can determine in a finite number of steps whether a polynomial over $ℚ$ is irreducible over $ℚ$?

I know there are algorithms, but is there one that works with all polynomials over $ℚ$?

Comment: The [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) looks for linear factors and terminates in finite time. I don't know whether there is a generalised form. [Eisenstein's criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eisenstein%27s_criterion) is very fast, but inconclusive most of the time.

Comment: You can reduce it to the case of polynomials with integral coefficients. Then you can look at a set of values of the polynomial and look for integral factors whose values are divisors of those values. Then do an interpolation and check whether you indeed got a divisor. Highly inefficient. Probably a mod $p$ interpolation for a bunch of primes $p$ plus factorization over $\mathbb{Z}/p$ is more efficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, such as Kronecker's method and the Zassenhaus algorithm. However, such algorithms usually perform full factorization. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials).